# Outlook and Google Calendar/Contacts Sync

Tags: windows, calendar, google-apps

I'm looking for a replacement for **google calendar sync** which was discontinued a while back.

I'm looking for a program that will do **two-way sync** between Microsoft Outlook and *non-business* Google Account. I **am** looking for:

1. Calendar Sync
2. Contacts Sync
3. Windows OS (7) & Outlook 2010 (or better) compatibility

I'm **not** looking for

- Mail because I can just set up mail via IMAP.
- I don't care about [tasks](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/task-manager-with-two-way-google-calendar-sync)

This should be able to **read and write** from Outlook to Google.

This is for personal use, **one account per computer** and I'm not really worried about price because I really just need to know what's still out there.

This is not for google apps, or I'd point to [google apps sync](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync).

I have tried [companionlink](http://www.companionlink.com/), but it's not syncing properly anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good experiences with both [iCal4OL](http://ical.gutentag.ch/) and [gSyncIt](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/). The latter syncs a lot more than just Google and is reasonably priced. Both products have licenses that are system-bound, not user-bound, so multiple copies need multiple licenses.

Comment: Thanks! I'd heard of gsyncit before, but I couldn't for the life of me remember the name.

Comment: iCal4OL is not going to be sold to new customers anymore http://ical.gutentag.ch/

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Sync2](http://www.sync2.com/). I wanted a free option, but couldn't find anything like that. Paid $19.99 for it. It syncs Calendar, Contacts, and Tasks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20104)

Comment: What is there more to add? The paid software does what the op wants. If I post a web archive link instead, your point becomes moot.