# Gratis Outlook addin that can sync with Google Calendar

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, google-apps, outlook

Now before we get going here, yes I did read [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3929/outlook-and-google-calendar-contacts-sync) question and found it was not suitable for my needs.

I am simply looking for an addin for Outlook that can do a two-way sync (both read and write calendar events) to Google's calendar. I have tried [gSyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/) however I am in a position where I need to sync more than one calendar and I do not have $20 lying around at the moment. The addin must be both gratis (free) and open source.

Requirements:

- Must be free and open source
- Must be able to sync more than one Google calendar (unlike the free version of gSyncit)
- Must have **two way communication** between me and Google's servers
- Must be very easy to use (one click sync or sync's automatically)
- Must work with Windows and Outlook 2013
- Should not contain any adware
- I'm fine with donationware so long as it does not force me to buy the addin

Note that I do not have a Google business account.

Answer (score 1):

Currently [Outlook Google Calendar Sync](http://outlookgooglecalendarsync.codeplex.com/) offers everything you're after except for multiple calendars.

Depending on what you need to achieve, you may be able to set this up through having multiple portable versions configured against different calendars in Outlook and Google.

As to your other requirements:-
- It's free and open source
- Two-way sync is configurable
- Very easy setup and one click sync or a scheduled sync is possible.
- Works with Windows and all version of Outlook (back to 2003)
- Contains no adware, but does have occasional prompts to donate
 - A standard Google account is sufficient

Comment: Could you please detail how it fits each of the other bullet requirements? Thanks!